# Suffle array by its sub arrays that have same field value

Tags: javascript

assuming I have an array of courses:

```
Courses:
  Course:
       name: 'Bible'
       grade: 87
  Course:
       name: 'Math'
       grade: 87
  Course:
       name: 'Physics'
       grade: 87
  Course:
       name: 'Biology'
       grade: 10
  Course:
       name: 'Geography'
       grade: 10
  Course:
       name: 'Literature'
       grade: 0
```

I want to shuffle the sub courses that have the same grades.

For example, one result can be (I am writing only the cources names, but need the entire fields):

```
Math, Bible, Physics, Geography, Biology, Literature
```

another result can be:

```
Bible, Math, Physics, Biology, Geography, Literature
```

Literature will be at the end, cause there is no another grade that equals to 0.

I have a function that suffles the array (without care the sub courses' grades):

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
```

The array is:

```
var courses = [];

courses.push(new Course('Bible', 87));
courses.push(new Course('Math', 87));
courses.push(new Course('Physics', 87));
courses.push(new Course('Biology', 10));
courses.push(new Course('Geography', 10));
courses.push(new Course('Literature', 0));

function Course(name, grade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

This is a jsfiddle that I have created: http://jsfiddle.net/Ht6Ym/3844/

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you please show the array

Comment: @user2181397, I have updated my topic. Thanks!

Comment: First shuffle, then sort by grade.

Comment: also can you please clarify what you mean by shuffle?

Comment: @user2181397 I assume the standard definition, "arrange in random order".

Comment: Since a standard sort is not guaranteed to be stable, simply sorting by `grade` should practically do it for all intents and purposes.

Comment: *"Literature will be at the end, cause there is no another grade that equals to 0"* - is this an additional requirement, that "lone" courses be at the end...?

Comment: For the example, there is no another course that has 0 grade. That's why literature will be in the end (the array is still sorted by grade, but each sub courses that have the same grade, have ordered randomly).

Comment: So Literature is at the end because its grade is `0`, not because it's "alone", right?

Comment: yes, right.. sorry for misunderstanding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort()` method with your two criteria.

Example:

```js
var courses = [{
       name: 'Bible',
       grade: 87
    },{
       name: 'Math',
       grade: 87
    },{
       name: 'Physics',
       grade: 87
    },{
       name: 'Biology',
       grade: 10
    },{
       name: 'Geography',
       grade: 10
    },{
       name: 'Literature',
       grade: 0
    }
  ];

courses.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.grade < b.grade || (a.grade == b.grade && Math.random() < 0.5) ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(courses);
```

Comment: The callback should return `-1`, `0` or `1`, not a boolean.

Comment: Thanks. That's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

use `dynamicSort` function with the array

```
function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a,b) {
        var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}

console.log(courses.sort(dynamicSort("grade")).reverse());
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/qm5b3qy0/)

Comment: Thank you, but the sort returns the same results:
"Physics", "Math", "Bible", "Geography", "Biology", "Literature".